# An inequality for the Darboux integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

As we know, if $f(x)$ are Riemann integrable, we have

\begin{gather}
\left|\int_a^b f(x)~\mathrm{d}x\right|\leq  \int_a^b |f(x)|~\mathrm{d}x.
\end{gather}

So, for Darboux integrals, such as the upper integral, do we also have

\begin{gather}
\left|\bar{\int_a^b} f(x)~\mathrm{d}x\right|\leq  \bar{\int_a^b} |f(x)|~\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\;?
\end{gather}

But how to prove it?

I think, we could use Darboux's theorem.

Let $P$ is a partition (segmentation) on closed interval $[a,b]$. And denote $\lVert P\rVert$ is largest of the lengths of the intervals of the partition P. We have

\begin{gather}
\lim_{\lVert P\rVert\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n M_i\Delta x_i=\bar{\int_a^b} f(x)~\mathrm{d}x,
\end{gather}
$M_i$ is the supremum on $[x_{i-1},x_i].$
Then we use Darboux sum to obtain

\begin{gather}
\left|\sum_{i=1}^n M_i\Delta x_i\right|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |M_i|\Delta x_i\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sup_{x\in \Delta x_i}|f(x)|\Delta x_i.\tag{2}
\end{gather}
Then I try to take limits on the left and right hand sides, but this limit is not the function's limit, they have a different definition. So I decide to prove these limits' inequalities.

Firstly, I give **Thm1:** For two Darboux uppers sum S(f;P) and S(g;P), where $P$ is a partition on [a,b], if
\begin{gather}
\lim_{\lVert P\rVert\to 0}S(f;P)<\lim_{\lVert P\rVert\to 0}S(g;P).
\end{gather}
Then, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that
\begin{gather}
S(f;P)<S(g;P)
\end{gather}
for all $P$ and point $\xi$ with $\lVert P\rVert<\delta.$

*Proof:* Let
\begin{gather}
 A:=\lim_{\lVert P\rVert\to 0}S(f;P),\quad B:=\lim_{\lVert P\rVert\to 0}S(g;P).
\end{gather}
Then we can find $C\in \mathbb{R}$ with $A<C<B.$So exist $\delta>0$, for all partition $P$ and points $\xi$ with $\lVert P\rVert<\delta$, we have

\begin{gather}
|S(f;P)-A|<C-A,\quad |S(g;P)-B|<B-C.
\end{gather}
Then we have
\begin{gather}
S(f;P)<A+(C-A)=C=B-(B-C)<S(g;P).
\end{gather}
Obviously we have $S(f;P)<S(g;P).$

Next, I give **Thm2:** For two Darboux upper sum S(f;P) and S(g;P), if there exists $\delta >0$ such that for all P and $\xi$ with $\lVert P\rVert <\delta$, we have
\begin{gather}
S(f;P)<S(g;P).
\end{gather}
then we have
\begin{gather}
\lim_{\lVert P\rVert\to 0}S(f;P)\leq\lim_{\lVert P\rVert\to 0}S(g;P).
\end{gather}
*Proof:* If
\begin{gather}
\lim_{\lVert P\rVert\to 0}S(f;P)>\lim_{\lVert P\rVert\to 0}S(g;P).
\end{gather}
This means there exists $\delta >0$ such that for any P with $\lVert P\rVert<\delta$ have
\begin{gather}
S(f;P)>S(g;P).
\end{gather}
But this is a contradiction, completing the proof.

I'm not sure these theorems whether correct and rigorous or not. If they are right, could I use it on inequality (2) to prove (1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from the inequalities
$$\sup A\le\sup|A| \tag{1}\label{1}$$
and
$$-\sup A\le\inf|A| \tag{2}\label{2}$$
for any set $A$ of real numbers, where $|A|:=\{|a|\colon a\in A\}$.

Indeed, take any "partition" $P=(x_0,\dots,x_n)$ of $[a,b]$, so that $a=x_0<\dots<x_n=b$. The corresponding upper Darboux sums for $f$ and $|f|$ are
$$S(f;P)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})\sup A_i$$
and
$$S(|f|;P)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})\sup|A_i|,$$
where $A_i:=\{f(x)\colon x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\}$.
So, by \eqref{1}, $S(f;P)\le S(|f|;P)$ and hence
$$\overline{\int_a^b} f=\inf_P S(f;P)\le \inf_P S(|f|;P)
=\overline{\int_a^b} |f|. \tag{3}\label{3} $$

Similarly, by \eqref{2}, $-S(f;P)$ is no greater than the lower Darboux sum $\underline S(|f|;P)$ and hence
$$-\overline{\int_a^b} f=-\inf_P S(f;P)=\sup_P(-S(f;P))\le \sup_P \underline S(|f|;P)
=\underset{-\!-\!-}{{\int _{a}^{b}}} |f|\le \overline{\int_a^b} |f|. \tag{4}\label{4} $$
(The penultimate integral $\underset{-\!-\!-}{{\int _{a}^{b}}} |f|$ in \eqref{4} is the lower Darboux integral of $|f|$. For some strange reason, MathJax is refusing to recognize the `\underline` in `\underline{{\int _{a}^{b}}}`; this code is working in regular LaTeX. Could anyone help with this? For now, I have crudely fixed this by using `\underset{-\!-\!-}` instead of `\underline`.)

It follows from \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} that
$$\Big|\overline{\int_a^b} f\Big|\le\overline{\int_a^b} |f|.\quad\Box $$